# How to prevent android soft keyboard from resizing my activity

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard

I've an activity that specified as dialog with this line in `Manifest` like this

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

so how to prevent soft Keyboard from pushing it up and resizing ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put `android:layout_height` solid not `match_parent` , `fill_parent` , `wrape_content` 
it should be a solid number like `android:layout_height="480dp"` or whatever

or we can specify it programmatically

using this code

```
Functions.setActivityDiemention(this,
            Functions.getScreenWidth(this) - 20,
            Functions.getScreenHeight(this) - 20);
```

before `setContentView`

**`setActivityDiemention` code**

```
public static final void setActivityDiemention(Activity activity ,int width,int hieght) {
    android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow()
            .getAttributes();
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = params.width;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes(
            (android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
}
```

`getScreenWidth` and `getScreenHeight`

**Code**

```
public static int getScreenHeight(Activity activity) {
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    if (getAPILevel() < 13) {
        return display.getHeight();
    }
    display.getSize(size);
    return size.y;
}

public static int getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    if (getAPILevel() < 13) {
        return display.getWidth();
    }
    display.getSize(size);
    return size.x;
}
```

and must use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Answer (score 21):

You can simply switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> 
</activity>
```

If you are using ScrollView add this too `android:isScrollContainer="false"` to the `ScrollView`.

Try it..

Comment: yes I've tried it but it doesn't work for me , to be more specific this activity is an `TabActivity` which contains 2 tabs

Comment: this is my manifest for `TabActivity` `<activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:name="mypakage.fragment.fillinformation.ChosePopUpMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chose_pop_up_menu"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>`